# Azure Application Gateway backendpool to Event Grid Topic

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-eventgrid

I would like to ask if it is possible to use Azure Application Gateway to route(backend pool) traffic to Azure Event Grid Topic. I have tested it but no matter what i do i always get 502 error when i tries to perform a POST Request to my App Gateway.

Here is the sample flow:

[user] ===> [Application Gateway]====>[EventGrid Topic]====> Azure Function

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got working, make sure you have the application setup as follows:

There is not a 'healthcheck' endpoint from Event Grid hence I just added the FQDN + /ping to the healthprobe and configured the probe to accept a 404.

In the HTTP settings you should make sure that the incoming hostname gets overrided with the EG FQDN by using the "Override with new hostname" option.
After that it should work just fine.Take a look at the rest of my HTTP settings below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, apology for late reply as I was away for a while to focus on a project. Let me test it out and thank you so much for your sharing…

Comment: Tested and it is working now. thank you so much.